# MATLAB - store variables with a specific prefix in .mat file

Tags: matlab, workspace

Is there a way to store just variables with a specific prefix inside a .matfile?

Example workspace variables:

```
a
b
c
d1
d1123fdwfwe
d23we
e
f
```

I am looking for a way to store for example just the variables with the prefix 'd' or the prefix 'd1' in a matfile.

Comment: You could get a list of your variables as a cell array of strings, find strings with your prefix, and then pass those strings to the `save` function. Why don't you try to code it up and we'll help you if you get stuck.

Comment: I hoped for a simple pre defined solution;) But okay, I will implement it like you said.

Comment: Actually, there is. It's in the docs, you can specify regular expressions http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) in [`save`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) to specify which variables are saved.

To save variables that begin with `d1`:

```
save('filename','-regexp', 'd1.*')
```

The regular expression `'d1.*'` indicates `'d1'` followed by zero or more characters.